# .htaccess show 404 page with rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a .htaccess file that essentially "removes" the file extension in the web browser (from example.php to example). Here's the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Basically, if the file (about) isn't found, it adds the .php extension (about.php). I want to (if the file still isn't found) redirect the user to 404.php.  So if the user loads /page1, and page1.php doesn't exist, it redirects to the 404 page. I added this code to the .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

On it's own, this code will redirect to the 404 page. But when I have the entire code...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /CWTC/404.php
```

...it just shows a "500 Internal Server Error".

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: check the server's error logs. it'll have more details on the 500 error.

Comment: @Marc B Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: `(.*)` will produce $1, so you're redirecting to whatever you'd matched.

Comment: @MarcB So how should I fix it?  I am a newbie with htaccess. :)

Comment: consider how it all works. you match the entire url, and append .php. that loops around again, matches everything, and appends .php again. now you're on about.php.php, and just keep looping and appending. You need a clause to EXCLUDE any links which already have .php

Comment: @MarcB Can you post the code that I'd need as an answer (not a comment) so I can try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has solved my problem:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Thanks!