# How to show a customized 404 page not found page when the file itself is non existent?

Tags: php, apache, automation, http-status-code-404

With this, I'm really stuck and I've searched for it in multiple forums. I am trying to create an automated page where if the user types in an invalid page, they automatically get a "whoops, page not found" page much like facebook or Twitter. I know I'm asking for a lot, and the question is pretty general, but I will reward every answer with reputation. The platform I would like to use is PHP on Apache.

Comment: Depends on the platform you're using. Is this asp.net running on IIS? Is it a rails or sinatra server? Is it PHP running on Apache? It's server dependent.

Comment: I edited the post with your above question

Answer (score 3):

since its running on apache, have a look at the selected answer here:

[.htaccess show 404 page with rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532119/htaccess-show-404-page-with-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by .htaccess.here is a link
   http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/